# Hiding URL key parameters with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameters, url-rewriting

I've been searching all over the web and haven't yet found any solution to this issue. I'm hoping you could shed some light on the situation.

I have my index file set up like this:

```
<header></header>
<div id="main">
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET["p"])) $p = $_GET["p"];
    else $p = "home";

    if(file_exists("pages/{$p}.php")) include("pages/{$p}.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

which makes me load my pages with a `?p=contact` href.

Say I would like to display a users profile. I'd then create a subfolder in my "pages" folder, making the relative path `pages/users/profile.php`, thus the href `?p=users/profile&uid=5`. But that leaves an ugly URL (as well as SEO rating).

How would I rewrite that URL to look like `/users/profile/5`?

---

**EDIT:**
I've tried the following, resulting in HTTP 500:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?p=$1&uid=$2 [L]
```

**EDIT:** My .htaccess file, located directly inside root folder: http://pastie.org/2268239 
Line 338 is where I want to achieve this (currently just a comment).

Comment: What Apache's error log says about error 500 reason?

Comment: @LazyOne Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Comment: That means that your rule (if it is only one here; if more -- then their combination) creates infinite rewrite cycle, which Apache has to forcibly break. You have to add condition that will break such cycle (e.g. add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before your rule -- but that is only a wild guess since I do not know all details). If this will not help -- then I strongly recommend enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log to see which rule causing it. Otherwise provide much more details (your current htaccess, where it located etc).

Comment: @LazyOne The .htaccess file is provided by HTML5 Boilerplate with my addition between lines 330-340. Updated post with pastie link.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Please post your solution as an answer (and accept it later), so that other people may reference to it (much better that see question with non-accepted answers and having to read whole page to see if it was solved or not). Thnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved the desired effect by adding these three lines:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?p=$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1&uid=$2 [L]
```

This allows me to access `/contact`, `/users/index` and `/users/profile/5`.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer for both your situations would be to add this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

This will redirect all traffic on your domain to your index.php file.

You could then determine what to do in your script using the uri in $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]

Comment: I modified a part of your third line to "/index.php?p=$1", because I think that's what you meant? However, that made my home page (blank URI) and 404 page (located directly inside root folder) to continously redirect to itself. Also, my external files (images,stylesheets,javascripts) wouldn't load.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a php guy, but I tried this with my rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?p=$1&uid=$2 [L]
```

In this case, for the `p` parameter, you're looking for all chars up to the last slash, so the first part of this takes anything, otherwise it's going to stop at the first slash (users instead of users/profile).

Then it looks for a slash and keep (not-slash). The `(.+)` will be greedy, so it will go up to the last slash before the end.

Then it occurred to me the last part doesn't need to avoid slashes. Since the first part is greedy, the explicit `/` slash is going to BE the last slash. So it's even simpler:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1&uid=$2 [L]
```

I like the `.+` to require something, at least when first figuring these out. If later you know they can be optional, you can do `.*`, but usually that ends up being a different page or a different rule.

These rules do expect all urls to be in this format, which is what you're asking. But maybe it's a little too grabby, so it could exclude urls that really have a .htm or .php or whatever.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/([^.]+)$ /index.php?p=$1&uid=$2 [L]
```

This looks for anything up to the last slash, then anything without a dot in it. If it has a dot, this won't apply. So if it's a "regular" url, this will leave it alone. This might help with the 404 problem, in case the 404 page is getting caught by this.

Comment: I tried both your additions, none of them seemed to make any changes in the behavior.

Comment: Edited to try a "tighter" rule, to leave regular urls alone. Maybe the 404 page is getting caught by this. Note these are all `[L]` last rules - not redirects. Also, when testing, try different urls, e.g., incrementing the number on the end - I'm having trouble with google chrome where it's caching my previous redirect/rewrite, and not getting new ones.